# あきらかに and らしい describing the same event

Tags: grammar

> おばさんもあきらかに危険に気づいたらしく、 ...
> It seemed that his aunt had also evidently noticed the danger and ...

Do あきらかに and らしく play nicely together in this sentence? It seems a bit contratdictory to me. あきらかに is suggesting that the thing is obviously true whereas らしく seems to be making that a mere conjecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what you are missing is that あきらかに is always (as far as I can think of) a sentence modifier.

彼女は明らかに危険に気付いた can be translated *She clearly noticed the danger*, which has an ambiguity: (1) clearly noticed or (2) it is clear that she noticed. あきらかに does not have this ambiguity and it is always (2). (I think *obviously* works similarly. It is always to the speaker that the thing is obvious).

らしい in 彼女は明らかに危険に気付いたらしい is a kind of weakener, making things indirect, as often happens in Japanese. Literally, it is *It **seemed** clear that she noticed the danger* (as opposed to *It **was** clear...*). As a translation, the second one in Eiríkr Útlendi's answer may be more natural.

So all in all, you interpreted it correctly but what you see as a contradiction is not necessarily so.

---

FYI.

- 彼女ははっきりと危険に気付いた

This one only means *She saw the danger clearly* or *The danger was obvious to her*. Appending らしい does not pose any contradiction - *It seemed (to me) that the danger was obvious to her.*

- 彼女は明らかに眠っていた She was obviously asleep/It was obvious that she was asleep.

Here there is no ambiguity due to the meaning of *asleep* (though *obviously asleep* may be less idiomatic). Note 彼女ははっきりと眠っていた is odd (as *to sleep clearly* is).

As a sentence modifier, 明らかに can be put in front. 明らかに彼女は... does not change anything in the above sentences.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this might be a matter of parsing.

I think you're looking at the phrase like this:

> おばさんもあきらかに（危険に気づいた）らしく

In this case, the あきらかに and らしく both apply to the core 危険に気付いた: she both "clearly" noticed the danger, but also only "apparently" noticed it, and we wind up with the apparent contradiction that you note.

Instead, we could parse this like so:

> おばさんも（あきらかに危険に気づいた）らしく

In this case, the あきらかに applies to the 危険に気付いた portion, and the  らしく then applies to this longer phrase: "it seems like" the aunt "clearly" noticed the danger.  Looked at this way, we avoid the contradiction.

Curious what others think, and I hope this helps.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did think about parsing it this way too, but I'm afraid I was equally unconvinced. It certainly seems like a valid interpretation but It doesn't seem to me like a natural thing anyone would ever say.  I think my problem might lie with the subtleties of what らしい actually implies. Have a +1, but I too am intrgued as to what others think.

Comment: @user3856370 Grammatically, the first reading should be correct. In English, isn't it possible to say *(It) obviously looked like (she) noticed ...* (even if a bit cumbersome)?

Comment: @sundowner "(it) obviously looked like (she) noticed" <-- this is certainly a valid sentence in English, but if you said that to me, my immediate thought would be that you were questioning my observational/deductive skills. i.e "it's clear to me that ... I'm surprised that you can't see it too". I'm certain that that isn't the implication in this particular sentence.

Comment: @user3856370 Perhaps the following comparison may be better: Just らしい is *it was apparent to me that ...* whereas あきらかに...らしい is *it was obvious to me that ...*. In *obviously looked like*,  what I meant is the *looked-like-ness* is intensified by *obviously* (which may not be how they sound in English).

Comment: @sundowner Yes, I think that works for me in English, but I'm still a little unhappy. It sounds like you are saying that  あきらかに is the judgement of the speaker, i.e. "To me it is clear that ...". However, the ordering of the words おばさんもあきらかに made me think that あきらかに applied the the aunt i.e. "it was clear to the aunt that ...". I know word order is less important in Japanese, but I wonder how we make this distinction? I have to sleep now, but I look forward to any further insight you might have. Thanks.

Comment: @user3856370 - おばさんもあきらかに危険に気づいたらしい does sound a bit weird to me. But おばさんもあきらかに危険に気づいたらしく、逃げ出した (just for example) doesn’t sound so weird. Remember that 〜らしく adverbially works on the part that follows. I think we could understand it as that the aunt’s subsequent action (of running away, for example) *appeared* (to the speaker) such that she clearly noticed the danger.

Comment: @aguijonazo Interesting. Your comment seems to contradict Sundowner's answer. He says that あきらかに must always apply to the speaker, whereas in your example it is applying to the aunt. Any thoughts? This is obviously ;-) more subtle than I thought.

Comment: @user3856370 - It was clear to the speaker the aunt noticed the danger, but it was the way she took the subsequent action, or the fact she did, that indicated that to the speaker, or something like that. It’s still a weird thing to say but for some reason the sentence doesn’t sound too weird if it continues after らしく. It’s hard to explain and harder to translate...

Answer (score 1):

明らかに～らしい sounds odd usually.

But this らしく(らしい) may be used when you hear something by someone.

Twitterで見たけど、社長が捕まったらしいよ
友達から聞いたけど、教頭より校長の方が若いらしい

If you hear someone says おばさんもあきらかに危険に気づいた, then you can say おばさんもあきらかに危険に気づいたらしく(らしい) without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

This らしい can also express that something is typical of something's characteristics. So it's more like the aunt noticed the danger, and she appears to be behaving accordingly.

Comment: When らしい expresses that, it follows a noun.